# How to export schema and its data with oracle forms 6i

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm dealing with oracle forms to create a backup of the user that Im connected to.
I have a textitem `:filepath`

and a button `:getfile` that will open file dialog, works fine.

```
declare
v_file_name varchar2(2000);
begin
:filepath := get_file_name(:filepath);
go_item('savefile');
end;
```

and the last button that will take the backup `:savefile`

```
HOST('exp userid=user/pass@orcl file=:filepath log=:filepath||.log grants=Y full=Y buffer=1024000');
```

when I pressed the button the cmd screen stuck and waiting for confirmed

```
EXP-00023: must be a DBA to do Full Database or Tablespace export
(2)U(sers), or (3)T(ables): (2)U >
```

I don't want the users to confirm any thing.  how to fix it?

Comment: What do these "Y/N" represent?

Comment: I think means YES / NO

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab NO I just update the question. have a look

Comment: @Littlefoot have a look again I just update it.

Comment: I presumed those were "Yes/No" :) Question was *what* caused them to appear. OK, I'm glad you fixed the problem with Abdullah's help.

Comment: @Littlefoot thank you… You helped me a lot with your answers here and at http://orafaq.com/ when I am having trouble. Abdullah's code works as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove `grants=Y`

```
    HOST('exp userid=user/pass@orcl file=:filepath log=:filepath||.log);
```

or you can create a profissional code and add the username, password, and connect_string dynamically...

```sql
DECLARE
   cmd    VARCHAR2 (255);
   un     VARCHAR2 (255) := GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY (username);
   pass   VARCHAR2 (255) := GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY (PASSWORD);
   conn   VARCHAR2 (255) := GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY (connect_string);
BEGIN
   cmd :='exp '|| un|| '/'|| pass|| '@'|| conn|| ' file='|| :filepath|| un|| '_'|| TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DDMMYYYY')|| '.dmp'|| ' log='|| :filepath|| un|| '_'|| TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DDMMYYYY')|| '.log';
   MESSAGE ('Exporting...', no_acknowledge);
   SYNCHRONIZE;
   HOST (cmd, screen);
   MESSAGE ('done');
   MESSAGE (' ');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      MESSAGE (SQLERRM);
END;
```

### Edit

**Note:**
That isn't a backup, that is an export and is not a true method for backing up a database

Hopefully, you do not use this for any data of any importance.

If you really want to backup use RMAN. here is you can statred... [Getting Started with RMAN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmquick.htm#BRADV89346)